# How to check if propery exist in HttpContext

Tags: .net, vb.net, http

I have the following code which tries to read user related saved data:

```
 res = HttpContext.Current.Profile.GetPropertyValue(properyName)
```

When there is no property it defined with properyName, an exception is thrown.
Is there a way to check if this property is defined without this exception?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way. As documentation on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.profile.profilebase.getpropertyvalue.aspx says, you should catch the exception and then determine that property is not available